# boost::assign static initialization of a large map with gcc4.6 not working

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I have a large map of data that is autogenerated using python which Is initialized using `boost::assign` as follows:

```
const my_large_map_type map_data = boost::assign::map_list_of(key1, type)
     (key2, type)
     (key3, type)
     (key4, type)
     // Lots of stuff
     (key6000, type)
     ;
```

This was working fine using GCC 4.3, the file compiled within a couple of seconds.

I have just tried to compile the same file using GCC compiler 4.6.3, as supplied by Texas Instruments for the ARM processor.

Unfortunately compilation of this file never completes, no errors are emitted.

Is this a known issue with GCC compiler 4.6.3?

Is there an alternative way that I could initialize the large map? I am currently un-able to use C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be an order-of-initialization error? If this is a static data structure and you are referencing it from the constructor of another static data structure (which is run before starting `main()`) then it's possible that it hasn't been initialised yet. Is the data created by the time you do reach `main()`?

An alternative way of setting up the initialisation would be to create it dynamically, but set it up inside a static variable that is initialised on demand, eg

```
static my_large_map_type& getMap() {
  static my_large_map_type gMap;
  if (gMap.empty()) {
    gMap = boost::assign::map_list_of(key1, type)
     (key2, type)
     ... ;
  }
  return gMap;
}
```

Comment: No this is during compilation. ie: `g++ file.cpp` using gcc 4.3 compiles the code in a couple of seconds; `g++ file.cpp` using gcc 4.6 never completes - it is still compiling 20 minutes later when I hit `Ctrl-C`